# Extract Float array from Data

Tags: swift

I have a function that receives a Data object together with a width and height. The data is a so called "normalised" image in binary form.
Each pixel consists out of 3 Float values for the R, G, B colors ranging from 0 -> 1.0 (instead of the typical 0-255 for UInt8 values, but here we have floats). In fact its a sort of 2 dimensional array with a width and a height like this:

[image]

How can extract the R, G, B values as Swift floats from the Data object? This is what I came up with so far:

```
    func convert(data: Data, width: Int, height: Int) {
        let sizeFloat = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: CGFloat.self)
        for x in 0...width {
            for y in 0...height {
                let index = ( x + (y * width) ) * sizeFloat * 3
                let dataIndex = Data.Index(???)
                data.copyBytes(to: <#T##UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<DestinationType>#>??, from: <#T##Range<Data.Index>?#>???)
           let Red = ....
           let Green = ...
           let Blue = ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that the ranges should be `0..<width` etc, *excluding* the upper bound.

Comment: Ok thx for headsup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`withUnsafeBytes()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes) to access the raw data as an array of `Float` values:

```
func convert(data: Data, width: Int, height: Int) {
    data.withUnsafeBytes { (floatPtr: UnsafePointer<Float>) in
        for x in 0..<width {
            for y in 0..<height {
                let index = (x + y * width) * 3
                let red = floatPtr[index]
                let green = floatPtr[index+1]
                let blue = floatPtr[index+2]
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I just could not figure out the UnsafePointer business (even with 10 years of past C++ experience I know all about pointers, but the syntax in Swift is a bit confusion). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

```
var r= data[0];
var g = data[1];
var b = data[2];

element.background-color =rgba(r,g,b,1)
```

perhaps your looking for something like this?

Comment: Data is a (NS)Data so I do not think this is possiblelike that

Comment: Can you show an example of your data, im confuse if its like this: [{23.4,44.5,11,2}] or like this [23.4,54.3,87.9]

Comment: Its a Swift data object so a blob of binary data

Comment: have you $log the data to see what it looks like after converting it back to utf-8 ?